# Saving data on referenced temporary table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I've added a temporary table using

```
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("CREATE TABLE #TmpTbl ... (Id uniqueidentifier not null primary key..)")
```

And I've referenced my temptable using

```
DbSet<TmpTbl> TmpTbl ..
```

In OnModelCreating I've identified my entity using

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TmpTbl>().ToView("#TmpTbl").HasKey(o => o.Id)
```

Fetching data works properly, but when I do TmpTbl.Add(new TmpTbl { .. }) and SaveChanges I get "Invalid object name 'TmpTbl'

Any good solution to solve this without using a third party library for temporary tables?

Comment: the error says '#TmpTbl' not 'TmpTbl', I just forgot to put the # there. The name is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested with EF Core 5, and to use a temp table here you need to configure the entity to map to a table, not a view:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TmpTbl>().ToTable("#TmpTbl").HasKey(o => o.Id);
```

And make sure you have a single open SqlConnection that spans the lifetime of the temp table.

eg

```
using (var db = new Db())
{
    db.Database.OpenConnection();
    var con = db.Database.GetDbConnection();
    
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("CREATE TABLE #TmpTbl  (Id uniqueidentifier not null primary key default newid(), Name nvarchar(200))");

    var t = new TmpTbl() { Name = "foo" };
    db.Set<TmpTbl>().Add(t);
    db.SaveChanges();

}
```

Comment: The issue was the connection. After I've started a BeginTransaction or OpenConnection everything works fine. Even with the ToView in Entity Framework Core.

Comment: In EFC5 you have to use ToTable, but also exclude it from migrations. modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>().ToTable("..", o => o.ExcludeFromMigrations()).HasKey(o => o.Id)